# Synchronize KMail and KOrganizer with my Google data

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, kde, kmail, korganizer

Is there a way to synchronize KMail and KOrganizer with my Google data?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this [blog post](http://blog.trumpton.org.uk/2010/02/kontact-gmail-sync-with-akonadi.html)? I think it may answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. The third para is scary, and makes me not want to do it.

Comment: Yeah a bit scary. I'm not using this but I thought it was worse a try (on one or 2 addresses), that may be the bug was now fixed. But I can understand you being reluctant to try it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.